# Find all $x \in \mathbb Z_{360}$ such that $x^2 ≡ 0 \pmod{360}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, prime-factorization

Find all $x \in \mathbb Z_{360}$ such that $$x^2 ≡ 0 \pmod{360}.$$

I know that this means to find all $x$ such that the result divides into $360$ evenly. I also know the prime factorization of $$360 = 2^3 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5 .$$

Is there a technique to use this prime factorization to easily come up with all the numbers that would satisfy this equation?

Thank you.

Comment: By $Z_{360}$, you mean  the numbers $1,2,...,360$?

Comment: Yes, the integers up to 360 in mod360 arithmetic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take any $x$ which is less than $360$.

Now, note that if $x = 2^a3^b5^c \times d$, where $d$ is some number coprime to $2,3,5$ (this can be done by unique factorization) then $x^2 = 2^{2a}3^{2b}5^{2c} d^2$.

We want $360$ to divide this number. That is, $360$ divides $2^{2a} 3^{2b} 5^{2c}d^2$. But, $360$ is coprime to $d^2$, because $d^2$ cannot share any prime factors with $360$ by the way we defined $d$.

Therefore, by a result we know :

> If $a$ divides $bc$ and $a$ is coprime to $c$, then $a$ divides $b$.

We get that $360$ divides $2^{2a} 3^{2b}5^{2c}$.
Now, what is $360$? It is $2^3 \times 3^2 \times 5$. For it to divide the above number, it follows that: $$
2a \geq 3, 2b \geq 2, 2c \geq 1 \iff a \geq 2,b \geq 1, c \geq 1  \tag{*}
$$

So, what we do know, is this : $360$ divides $2^{2a} 3^{2b} 5^{2c}$, if and only if the right hand side of $(*)$ hold true.

Let $n$ be any natural number. Note that if $360$ divides $2^{2a} 3^{2b} 5^{2c}$, then it also divides $2^{2a} 3^{2b}5^{2c} \times n$.

Therefore, put $a = 2,b=1,c=1$ : since the right hand side of $(*)$ is satisfied, so 360 divides the square of $2^2 \times 3 \times 5 = 60$, and therefore the square of every multiple of $60$ as well.

This tells us that the answer to the given question have to be multiples of $60$. Alternately, it is not difficult to see that every multiple of $60$ does satisfy the conditions. So the answer is precisely multiples of $60$ in $Z_{360}$.

Comment: It's a little confusing that d is coprime with 360 at the start, but then you re-use d as "some natural number" which is not necessarily coprime with 360 at the end.

Comment: @StevenIrrgang Oh, I see. I will sort it out. But have you at least understood up till the second last line? (Where the problem is).

Comment: @StevenIrrgang Please check for errors now. Thank you for inspection : you are improving the quality of the answer.

Comment: No worries, could follow it before despite that minor issue and looks correct to me now.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I completely followed your explanation. So 0, 60, 120, 180, 240, 300, and 360 are all the possible x values?

Comment: Yes, expect $0$ and $360$ are the same really, so we have six such values.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  $x^2 \equiv 0 \mod 360$ iff $x^2 \equiv 0 \mod 2^3, \mod 3^2 \ \text{and} \mod 5$.